# Maximizing a function whose maximum is where the derivative is not defined

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I would like to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}  & 52 - 4(x-1)^{2/3} - x^2 \\
\text{subject to}& x\ge 0 \\
&x \le 11
\end{array}

I know that the answer is $x=1$, a point in which the derivative of the function is not defined.

How could I find that using traditional Lagrangean multipliers?
This is how I started:

$$L(x,\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}) = 52 - 4(x-1)^{2/3} - x^2 + \lambda_{1}x+\lambda_{2}(11-x)$$

Which yields the following first order conditions:

\begin{align}
-\frac83(x-1)^{-1/3} - 2x + \lambda_{1} - \lambda_{2} = 0 \\
\lambda_{1}x=0 \\
\lambda_{2}(11-x)=0 \\
x \ge 0, x \le 11 \\
\lambda_{1} \ge 0, \lambda_{2} \ge 0
\end{align}

After some calculations I found out that $\lambda_{1}$ has to be $0$. However, if $\lambda_{1} =0$, then $\lambda_{2} = 0$. This leads to:

$$ -\frac83(x-1)^{-1/3} - 2x =0$$

Which has no solution.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Obviously you won't find $x=1$ because you pointed out that the derivative does not exist at that point and the first KKT condition is about stationarity.

Comment: The derivative is $-2 x-\frac{8}{3 \sqrt[3]{x-1}}$

Comment: @LinAlg so using the lagrangean will not give me my solution? After finding no solution I should have just supposed that the point $x=1$ would give me my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is this: people often forget that critical numbers aren't only where the derivative is equal to $0$, but they are also where the derivative is undefined.

The process I advise people to take is this:

1) Are you constrained by intervals? If so, include any interval endpoints as critical numbers.

2) Are you able to find the derivative of your given function? If so, find where the derivative is equal to $0$, and **also**, if applicable, find where your derivative is undefined.

The set of $x$-values that are gathered from steps 1) and 2) above are your critical numbers.

In this situation, we see that $0$, $11$ are critical numbers immediately, and since the derivative is undefined at $x = 1$, $1$ is also a critical number. Thus, all three of these numbers should be tested. You should input these values into the objective function and compare their outputs directly.

Note that IF the $x$-value $x_0$ is the location of a local extrema AND a function $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, it is the case that $f^{\prime}(x_0) = 0$. But this DOES NOT mean that if $f^{\prime}(x_0) = 0 \implies $ there is an extrema at $x_0$. Take $f(x) = x^3$ for example.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! But I guess then that using Lagrange mulitpliers would not point out to all of these values gathered from your points 1 and 2?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I'm not sure how Lagrange multipliers could work in this situation. Aren't Lagrange multipliers meant to only work with equality constraints, rather than inequalities? I suppose you could look at this with a linear programming perspective, but I don't have much background there.

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Now that I've looked at your Lagrange multiplier part of your question: it's not surprising to me that there is no solution: reason being that since Lagrange multpliers are meant to work with equality constraints, you applied two constraints with your work: $x = 0$ and $x = 11$. Obviously, these constraints cannot occur simultaneously and hence you have no solution with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Not sure if I am using the right words then. My book says that if I have a constrained optimization problem with inequalities, I could something similar with the lagrangian function. The difference would be the first order conditions: I would have to add that $\lambda_{1}x=0$ and that $\lambda_{2}(11-x)$ = 0

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I'm not familiar with this idea unfortunately.